# How to handle multiple popups opened simultaneously in Playwright Automation using typescript

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, playwright, dynamics-crm-uci

I After clicking one control from dialog box I m getting a popup but there is already a popup behind the dialog box. I want to verify the newly opened popup message but  control is taking the message of existing opened popup rather than new one.
Can someone help me with how to handle that?

Comment: Hi, have you seen: https://playwright.dev/docs/multi-pages

Comment: Already tried with that but it's not working